# Find Periodicity in Lightcurve Using Lombscargle Periodogram

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

I am trying to find the periodicity in lightcurve using the Lombscargle periodogram. I have tried the to find using astropy Lombscargle function. But I couldn't figure out how to give the value for Nyquist factor. My data is unevenly sampled data of about 10 years. My time axis is in mjd. Any suggestions would be great help to find periodicity using Lombscargle in python. I have look into the repository of vanderplas to find the lombscargle but couldn't figure it out properly.

Comment: Might this be better suited for Astronomy SE?

Comment: Astronomy SE ? I couldn't get it.

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is a generic question concerning Nyquist and Lomb-Scargle for unevenly-sampled data, so could go anywhere really, physics, astronomy, statistics, math, biology, whatever.

Comment: @rfl I just thought that it might get a better answer on Astronomy SE since it is in the context of astronomical lightcurves.